# Typescript: Why is an omitted generic type an object?

Tags: typescript, generics, default

I wondering why is the default generic type an object `{}` and not `any`?
It behaves like an any, but is a bit confusing.

[Example / Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-generic-type-default?embed=1&file=index.ts&view=editor)

```
class Foo<T> {}

// The type of this:
const foo = new Foo();
// is {} but expected any or error.
```

I could use:

```
class Foo<T = any> {}
```

But I want to know the background behind. I think it's because `T` is object-like.

Another concern: How to force the developer to set an type for the generic class?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5884 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5254 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5884 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27288

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior typescript has with regard to generic type parameters. It tries to infer them, if it can't it defaults to the narrowest possible type, which if you don't have any constraints on `T` is `{}`

As @Paleo points out in the comments there is a [proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27288) to create a `strict` option for this but this is not available at present:

In the meantime, if we want to enforce the specifying of parameters we can play around with the constructor parameters, in order to get an error if not type parameter is specified:

```
class Foo<T = void> {
    constructor(...a: T extends void ? ["Supply A type arg"] : []) {

    }
}

const foo1 = new Foo(); // err
const foo2 = new Foo<number>();
```

**Note** I would use this trick sparingly, prefer having an argument to the constructor that would  let the compiler infer `T`. Even without this trick, eventually you would probably get an error that `{}` is not what you might expect it to be, although traking down the error may be an issue.